Window tiling keyboard shortcuts on Tuxedo OS
My goal is to assign keyboard shortcuts to window tiling, and also be able to control things like padding and spacing around the windows.  This would be similar to Rectangle for MacOS.  I'm running the latest version of Tuxedo OS.  Here's some things I tried:
SMBAct
This program seems to buggy and too unstable to use.  There's no installer, and once I got the program running it would work for a few minutes and then just turn "white" and not let me do anything.  Gave up on it pretty quickly.
Bismuth
It does seem to install using sudo apt install kwin-bismuth, but then it wants me to go to System Settings > Window Management > Window Tiling which there's no such thing.  I'm guessing the version of KDE I'm using (KDE Plasma 6.1.3) doesn't have this feature.
Tuxedo Smart Windows
This feature is built into the OS and would actually be perfect.  You can hit Meta+T to configure your zones, and then hold down shift while dragging a window to move a window into that zone.  However, there's no keyboard shortcuts to move a window to a zone so it's not that useful for me.
Quick Tile KWin Shortcuts
I can configure this which almost does what I want:

However, the windows go right to the edge of the desktop and I want a little bit of buffer between windows and the edge of the desktop.
Window Gaps
I used to use this one which worked great!  However, it doesn't work on KDE6.
Any other options I'm missing?  Thanks!

I found one solution, though it's not perfect.  I think it'll work good enough for me.  This uses the KWin tile-gaps script as well as an unmerged (and since abandoned!) attempt to port the script to KDE6.
First, you'd want to clone the repo:
gh repo clone nclarius/tile-gaps
cd tile-gaps

Next, pull down the KDE6 PR, which has since been deleted but still accessible:
gh pr checkout 24

Now, you should be able to install the script using:
./install.sh

Note, you might have to run:
rm -rf /home/mike/.local/share/kwin/scripts/tilegaps

All around, this seems to work but it's extremely buggy (hence why the PR was never merged).  I had all sorts of issues trying to change the config and apply the new config, often having to uninstall and reinstall.  However, once you get it installed and the padding settings right, it seems fairly stable.
I might mess around with the code some and see if I can improve it, since the code is pretty simple and all in main.js.
